# CAML Query Last List Item Where Status = New

Tags: javascript, custom-list, caml-query, cewp, camlviewfields

I have a SharePoint 2013 custom list and a requirement to load the last list item where Status = New. I first tried SPGetLastItemID with a CAML query filter - however, that method only returns items for the current user, and I need the last item where Status = New for ALL items/users.

For some reason I can't seem to get this working (no alert box):

```
var LastID;
function QueryLastNewStatusItem() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var List = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Tracker');
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var textCaml ="
        <View> 
        <RowLimit>1</RowLimit> 
        <Query> 
            <OrderBy> 
            <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /> 
            </OrderBy>
            <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Status' />
                <Value Type='Text'>New</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where> 
        </Query>
        </View>";
    query.set_viewXml(textCaml);
    var item = List.getItems(query);
    context.load(item);
    LastID = GetItemID(item);
    alert(LastID);
}
```

I am beginner level with JavaScript and pretty new to CAML queries. I did use internal names for FieldRef Names within the query and made sure that the function is firing.

Comment: Can you please also add the GetItemID function?

Comment: I ended up removing that step since I can pull what I need from that item once it's loaded without having the ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the step of getting the item's ID since I can pull what I need from that item once it's loaded without having the ID, I also changed the format of the query (if writing it as multi-line each line needs to be in quotes with a "+" on the end. I also inserted the query directly into query.set_viewXml() rather than creating a variable for it. Now it's working great!

```
function QueryLastNewStatusItem() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var List = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Tracker');
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>New</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
    this.collListItem = List.getItems(query);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert("query suceeded");
}

function onQueryFailed() {
    alert("query failed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using below query on Status field:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='Status' />
     <Value Type='Choice'>New</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

> **Note**: Assuming that Status field is a `Choice` field.

---

I would recommend you to utilize the tool that will help you build your CAML Queries easily, for example [U2U Caml Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Software)

[image]

Comment: It is indeed a choice field, I will give that a try. And thanks for the tool recommendation! : )

Comment: Welcome, and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Interestingly, it works both ways (with "Text" or "Choice"). I was able to change my method a bit and got it working (see below).

Comment: Great. Glad to hear that you got it working.